How to auto deploy AWS lambda functions to multiple aws accounts
I am working on AWS lambda functions using python and SAM deployment.Already i am deploying in one account with two environments. If i need to deploy it to multiple AWS accounts, then how to auto deploy all lambdas to those both accounts and how to manage  table names and api in the lambda?
I have tried only deploying each lambda one by one to each account separately and by changing table names. I need to auto deploy all lambdas to both accounts having multiple accounts table name

have you considered using a CI/CD tool? for example, you can use github actions to management the deployment depending on the branch, so when code is merged to dev it deploys to dev account, main branch to prod account. You can easily manage/set different environment variables/params so the table names change depending on where you are deploying from.
